# Using yt to annotate particles on a scene/volume rendering

Tags: python, scene, particles, volume-rendering, yt

As the title says, I am trying to use yt in python to create a 3d rendering of a scene and then I am trying to annotate particles onto the scene. I'm using a AMRe-Ex data set with a boxlib for the volume rendering.
`ds = yt.load("plt00000") sc = yt.create_scene(ds,("boxlib","ep_g"))`

I am then trying to annotate the particles onto the 3d rendering, but the scene has no annotate_particles attribute like the 2d plots. I was wondering if there was any good way to overlay the particles onto the 3d rendering using yt?

Ive tried using sc.annotate_particles but I got the error "scene has no attribute 'annotate particles'". When I try to plot the particle data directly, I keep running into problems too. The most common is the `sc=yt.create_scene` doesnt seem to accept the data type.